# using CSS file in Jquery in C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a bit of Jquery code the expands a tree menu and MVC 5 app and when I hard code the style in the view it works.  However I want to place the code in the CSS file I have the others in, but when I move it in there it only seems to partially work.

view file the controller is calling:

```
@model List<OrwellFrontEnd.Models.SiteMenu>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Simple";

}


@section AddCustomStylesToHead{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

@section Treeview
{
    <section class="Treeview">
        <div class="container body-content">
            <h2>Simple Treeview from Database Data</h2>
            <div style="border:solid 1px black; padding:10px; background-color:#FAFAFA">
                <div class="treeview">
                    @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        <ul>
                            @TreeviewHelper.GetTreeView(Model, Model.FirstOrDefault().ParentMenuID)
                        </ul>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}

@* Here We need some Jquery code for make this treeview collapsible *@
@section Scripts{
    <script>        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".treeview li>ul").css('display', 'none'); // Hide all 2-level ul
            $(".collapsible").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).toggleClass("collapse expand");
                $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<p> It is body of Index view that renders in BodyRender.</p>
```

Style code that is now in ~/Content/Site.css

```
/*Here We will add some css for style our treeview*/
.collapse {
    width: 15px;
    background-image: url('../Contetn/Images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -36px -17px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.expand {
    width: 15px;
    background-image: url('../Content/Images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -50px -17px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.treeview ul {
    font: 14px Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.treeview > li > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.treeview li {
}

    .treeview li a {
        padding: 4px;
        font-size: 12px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: auto;
    }
```

And below is the layout page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @if (IsSectionDefined("AddCustomStylesToHead"))
    {
        @RenderSection("AddCustomStylesToHead", required: false)
    }
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderSection("Treeview", required: false)
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

It's probably a mess now as been trying to tinker.  It seems to sort of work as if I change with width or padding and other attributes in the Treeview li/ui of the style it does affect the page, but the image isn't displaying when it is in the css file but works fine when I have it in the view directly.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: What does "it only seems to partially work" mean? Only some styles are getting applied but not others?

Comment: by partially works i guess you mean some of the styles are applied... make sure you put the styles at the bottom of the CSS file if you want these styles to get applied to matter what. Also if some are still not being applied check to see where the elements are currently getting their styles from... you may have to put !important for those styles

Comment: Yes, some of thr padding and font size seems to affect it but it's the image that isn't displaying and can't get it to do so.  How does the important work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can use "head" in that view - You're editing inside the body already.

You can use the below solution unless you're using a partial view.

In the layout-page, add a new section:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @if (IsSectionDefined("AddCustomStylesToHead"))
    {
        @RenderSection("AddCustomStylesToHead", required: false)
    }
</head>
...
```

Then in your views, you can use the following to add additional css:

```
@section AddCustomStylesToHead{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/MyPage.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

**Update**

From the comments, and your updated question, it is clearly a problem with relative paths and/or css.

So, a few fixes:

Only keep one of the links to "Site.css" in your _Layout. I would keep the one with @Url.Content. Also you can remove the code I suggested you to add, since that was not your issue at all (remove from both _Layout and the view).

Possible Wrong relative path:

```
background-image: url('../Content/Images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png');
```

Should, probably, be (if you have "Images" in it's own folder, directly under to project root):

```
background-image: url('../Images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png');
```

If you have the image-folder as a subfolder to "Content" though, this would work:

```
background-image: url('Images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png');
```

Spelling error:

```
url('../Contetn/Images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png');
```

But that will resolve itself if you "correct" the paths.

Remove empty style:

```
.treeview li {}
```

It's just not needed.

One last thing, since I noticed you use Bootstrap. If there is a conflict in styles between your css and bootstraps, the bootstrap style will win. For example I suspect that ".collapse" is a bootstrap style, so yours will be overwritten.

To change this you can put your link to "Site.css" after Bootstraps (in the head _Layout). Bootstrap might still overwrite certain things, but at least you have a bigger chance of "winning".

Comment: Thanks but no luck.  I have a _ViewStart page that points to the _Layout.cshtml if that makes any difference.

Comment: _ViewStart has nothing to do with this, no. All your css files should be defined in _Layout (since this is where the head is). In later versions of MVC this is done using bundles, but that's a whole other question. Just saying "no luck" is not really giving me much to go on. Put a bit of effort in to it, and provide more details to what you are trying and what the results are.

Comment: ugh, that's not very readable. Since you are new here on SO: Never post code in comments as it's not formatting correctly and it's not easily visible for other users. Update your original question with the relevant code - that is where people will look first. Regarding your code: You have included "Site.css" already (not once, but three times now) and it seems fine. The problems you are having must be IN the css file. Feel free to include some bits of that in your question too.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping with this.  Yes it was in Images/Site.css but tried moving it into the content as that was where the css was.  Accidently came across how too debug and seen the display: inline-block was being overwritten.  Trying to work out now what is doing that but thats the problem!  have moved the Images folder back to the root though :)  Sorry for the mess, I'm a database guy, only been looking at MVC.html/css etc for like 3 days!

Comment: As I wrote in the end of my answer, .collapse is probably used by Bootstrap. If you can, you should change your class names to be a bit more unique: like .myCollapse, .myExpand, etc. Sometimes you want to use the same name though, if you want to add to the original definition. If you must overwrite something, you can use !important. This is not recommended outside of testing and debugging though: display: inline-block !important;

Comment: Much appreciated.  For some reason I thought a tutorial I had done said that if you hard code it in cite.css that overrules the bootstrap.  oh well, learn by doing! :)

I'll change them to be unique from bootstrap.